# How to calculate term score using implement information gain in solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, machine-learning

How to calculate term score implementing information gain in solr? How to customize the lucene tf-idf scoring algorithm to produce better relevancy in search results?

Answer (score 1):

The scoring algorithm is defined in a [`Similarity`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html).  you can implement your scoring logic extending `Similarity`, and then set it as your Similarity implementation to `IndexWriterConfig` and `IndexSearcher`.

The default Similarity is [`DefaultSimilarity`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/DefaultSimilarity.html) (whoda thought, right?).  If you just want to modify scoring, you can extend that, or it's parent class [`TFIDFSimilarity`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html).